# How to create protected routes in Nextjs14 only on client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a backend which uses JWT for authentication and on the browser, I'm storing this JWT token in local storage.

Now in my frontend, I'm using app router in Next.js 14. Is there a way I can check before each page whether the token is valid, and if so, then allow user to go to that page, else it should redirect to login page.

Comment: what is your method for authenticating users? did you using specific package like next-auth or ... ?

Comment: Nope, I have used my own login/signup components on frontend, and auth apis are on python server.